# I have an Exception in Tkinter callback

Tags: tkinter

am making a password generator using tkinter it saves the input to a json file it was working before but now whenever i try to save, its bringing the Exception in Tkinter callback error here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import pyperclip
import json
# ---------------------------- PASSWORD GENERATOR ------------------------------- #
import random
def password_generator():
    letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

    nr_letters = random.randint(8, 10)
    nr_symbols = random.randint(2, 4)
    nr_numbers = random.randint(2, 4)

    password_list = []

    for char in range(nr_letters):
      password_list.append(random.choice(letters))

    for char in range(nr_symbols):
      password_list += random.choice(symbols)

    for char in range(nr_numbers):
      password_list += random.choice(numbers)



    random.shuffle(password_list)

    password = ""
    for char in password_list:
      password += char
    passinput.delete(0,END)
    passinput.insert(0, password)
    pyperclip.copy(password)
# --------------sbh-------------- SAVE PASSWORD ------------------------------- #
def save():
    get_web=webinput.get()
    get_pass=passinput.get()
    get_mail=emailinput.get()
    new_data={
        get_web: {
            "email": get_mail,
            "password":get_mail
        }
    }


    if len(get_web) and len(get_mail) and len(get_pass) != 0:
        is_ok= messagebox.askokcancel(title="Website", message=f"These are the details you entered: \nEmail:{get_mail}"
                                                        f"\n Website: {get_web} \n Password: {get_pass} \n  is it ok to save?")

        if is_ok:
            with open("data.json","r") as data_file:
                data=json.load(data_file)
                data.update(new_data)

            with open("data.json", "w") as data_file:
                json.dump(data, data_file, indent=4)
            webinput.delete(0,END)
            passinput.delete(0,END)

    elif len(get_web) or len(get_mail) or len(get_pass) == 0:
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Error", message="Dont leave any of the field empty")
# ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #
window= Tk()
window.title("Password Generator")
window.minsize(width=500, height=500)
window.config(padx=20,pady=20,bg="#B1DDC6")
my_img= PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas=Canvas(height=200,width=200)
canvas.create_image(100,100,image=my_img)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)

webtext=Label(text="Website:")
webtext.grid(column=0,row=1)
webinput=Entry(width=35)
webinput.focus()
webinput.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2)

webemail=Label(text="Email/Username:")
webemail.grid(column=0, row=2)
emailinput=Entry(width=35)
emailinput.insert(END,string="ayodeledanny4@gmail.com")
emailinput.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2)

passtext=Label(text="Password:")
passtext.grid(column=0,row=3)
passinput=Entry(width=21)
passinput.grid(column=1,row=3)

generate_button=Button(text="Generate Password", command=password_generator)
generate_button.grid(column=2,row=3)

add_button=Button(text="Add", width=36, command=save)
add_button.grid(column=1,row=4,columnspan=2)




window=mainloop()
```

here is the. error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/python projects/password-manager-start/main.py", line 56, in save
    data=json.load(data_file)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 6 column 1 (char 115)
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/Downloads/python projects/password-manager-start/main.py", line 56, in save
    data=json.load(data_file)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 6 column 1 (char 115)
```

Comment: Judging by the traceback, it looks like you're feeding it bad json data. Have you examined the data to verify that it's valid json?

Comment: yes the json is valid

Comment: oh found it i used emailinput.get() as the password data instead of it being passinput.get() but should that affect it should still work regardless since they are both string. Infact the first data in the json file stored the password as gmail

Comment: infact i used get mail jow and it still work why did it fail the other time

Comment: i run it again and we have this new error